# Open Source software for email campaigns

Tags: email

I'm migrating from a Windows based server to Linux.  One of the last holdouts on the Windows machine is "Campaign Manager", a software tool that runs a query on our member database, generates a list of emails and then emails them all, tracking bounces and other stats.  I'd like to find a good replacement on Linux, but I don't have much experience with mass email software.

Can you give me a recommendation of software you have personal experience with?

Comment: If you're not a spammer, and this question is in regards to legit email, then why did you tag it as "spam"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my colleagues uses PHP List. While I installed it for him, I haven't used it myself, but he appears to be quite happy with it.

http://www.phplist.com/